# Wordpress Permalinks Redirect htaccess

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

In my old wordpress blog are the permalinks day and title for example `/2020/02/17/example-title/`.
I will change it to `/example-title/`.

Now I need a redirect code for all the old links with the date in the URL.
I didn't find here or elsewhere a solution for this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your new blog simply a copy of the old one? Is there any reason you cannot just reset the permalinks via Settings → Permalinks to the new format?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working solution:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+)/$ https://www.example.com/$4
```